# Spark Scala: GroupByKey and sort

Tags: scala, sorting, apache-spark, combiners

I have a `RDD` with the following structure:

```
val rdd = RDD[ (category: String, product: String, score: Double) ]
```

My objective is to `group` the data based on category, and then for each category `sort` w.r.t. score of `Tuple 2 (product, score)`. As for now my code is :

```
val result = rdd.groupByKey.mapValues(v => v.toList.sortBy(-_._2))
```

This turns out to be very expensive operation for the data I have. I am looking to Improve performance using alternative approach.

Comment: Why is it so important to sort?

Comment: It might help if you could give rough sizes - how many items in the original RDD, how many categories, how many items per category on average. How long is this taking, on what sort of hardware? How fast do you need it to be?

Comment: How do you plan to consume the sorted data? Do you plan to iterate through all of them, do you just want to find the top one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Difficult to answer without knowing your dataset, but the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions) has some clues re: `groupByKey` performance:

> Note: This operation may be very expensive. If you are grouping in
>   order to perform an aggregation (such as a sum or average) over each
>   key, using PairRDDFunctions.aggregateByKey or
>   PairRDDFunctions.reduceByKey will provide much better performance.

So it depends what you intend to do with the sorted lists. If you need the whole of every list, then it may be difficult to improve on `groupByKey`. If you are performing some kind of aggregation, then the alternative operations above (`aggregateByKey`, `reduceByKey`) may be better.

Depending on the size of your lists, it *may* be more efficient to use an alternative collection (e.g. mutable Array) before sorting.

**Edit**: If you have a relatively small number of categories, you could try filtering the original RDD repeatedly, and sorting each filtered RDD. Although a similar amount of work is done overall, it may use less memory at any given moment.

**Edit 2**: If lack of memory is a problem, you might be able to represent your categories and products as integer IDs rather than Strings, and only lookup the names later. This way, your main RDD could be much smaller.

Comment: yes, I need to keep all the entire list. This corresponds to a business case where for each category, I need to list the products based on their ranks.

Answer (score 0):

Is your RDD fairly distributed on categories ? You could have issues depending on your skew factor.
Try something like this if you don't have too many key values :

```
val rdd: RDD[(String, String, Double)] = sc.parallelize(Seq(("someCategory","a",1.0),("someCategory","b",3.0),("someCategory2","c",4.0)))

rdd.keyBy(_._1).countByKey().foreach(println)
```